# Rotates rolling_window with the robot

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, local-costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've a doubt. Can I use a rolling window in local_costmap that rotates with the robot? Because I'd like use local_costmap rectangular oriented with the robot.

I tried to set ***local_costmap/global_frame: /base_link***. Local_costmap rotates with the robot, but base_local_planner has some problems to navigate in correct mode.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204410/rotates-rolling_window-with-the-robot/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The costmap_2d package does not support rotating costmaps.

The rolling_costmap forces the orientation of the costmap to remain stable. This makes it easier to shift the data as the window "rolls". The orientation is a lot more difficult to transform the data, and the costmap does not currently support it.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1